# Passing a model to several viewmodels

Tags: caliburn.micro

I am starting a large WPF application which I will spice up with Caliburn.micro.
I have three views with corresponding viewmodels who all talk to the *same* instance of a model.

How can I pass the model to the viewmodels using Caliburn.micro?

The problem arises from the need for several viewmodels to access the same model instance.
It is essentially different parts of the model's functionality that is being split up into smaller parts (VM's and V's) because often not all of the model's functionality is needed.

Comment: Since a viewmodel is a class you can add another class to it's constructor. Can you make the question a bit clearer. Are you using a IOC container ? Are you working viewmodel or view first ?

Comment: @Marwijn Clarified the question a bit. I am not using an IoC container and I am using viewmodel first.

Comment: If you are not using an IOC container, I assume you are creating your viewmodels with new. What is preventing you from adding the Model to the constructor ?

Comment: An IOC container would resolve and inject (a singleton of) the model instance into the ViewModels. There is no reason why you can't do this manually via constructors on your VMs, or by using a singleton/static instance of your model. The thing I can't get my head round is a large WPF application with only 3 views...?!

Comment: @Marwijn I don't know how to instantiate the model that would have to be injected into the viewmodel.

Comment: What is your model, a C# class ? What is the reason you cannot instantiate it ?

Comment: @Charleh Must it be a implemented as a singleton for the IoC to work? The application has more than 3 views, but it has exactly 3 views that have viewmodels who needs the same model.

Comment: @Marwijn Yes it's just a C# class so the instantiation can be done of course, but where would I instantiate it and inject into the viewmodels? In the bootstrapper? Usually I have my viewmodels instantiate the models, but since in this case they're sharing one, that approach does not work.

Comment: Ah right, well usually when configuring an IoC container you specify the lifestyle of the service that you require. The default for say `Castle.Windsor` is `Singleton`, meaning that when the container resolves a particular service, it will resolve the same instance no matter where the resolution happens. If you wanted to inject the same instance of a model into three different views you would likely give the service a `Singleton` lifestyle and the container would do the rest. I have a feeling that your requirements aren't quite so straightforward - can you explain your architecture a bit more?

Comment: Also if you had some sort of 'Shell' viewmodel or conductor which managed the 3 viewmodels, you could simply pass the model into the 3 viewmodels via the constructor. It does depend on your architecture...

Comment: @Charleh I have not yet settled on an architecture. I do have a ShellViewModel. What would the model passing to the viewmodels look like?

Comment: I would go with Charleh and use an IOC container. However since you are not using one, you can create your Model in the bootstrapper and pass it along to the ViewModels.

Comment: @Marwijn I will perhaps use an IoC container, but for now, I would like to explore the possibilities. Will Caliburn automatically wire up the views for the viewmodels (which, I guess, also needs to be instantiated in the bootstrapper) ?

Comment: Wiring up the Views to ViewModels is done by Caliburn.Micro provided that you follow the naming conventions of it. Creating Viewmodels and other classes is in generally not something for Caliburn, but for an IOC container (e.g. Castle.Windsor). I suggest you check out the documentation and samples of Caliburn.Micro.

Comment: Do you have any sort of implementation yet - if you do can you post some details about it as it might help us answer the questions and also help decide if you need to go the IoC route or can get away without it. Chances are, with a big project, for reasons of testability, maintainability etc it is worth using an IoC container - there isn't that much extra setup and it helps you architect your solution to be as robust as possible

Comment: So far, I have no implementation at all. I will mess around in the next few days, and can post the results then.